# there is no tenant concept in WSO2 ML?

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-ml

I am using Machine Learner (ML) of wso2 and I found that no have the possibility of create a new tenant. There is no  this concept in ML ??. How I can access a event created in DAS by certain tenant ???

Answer (score 0):

Multitenancy is not supported in current ML versions (1.0.0 and 1.1.0). You can integrate ML with DAS by following this guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML110/Integration+with+WSO2+Data+Analytics+Server and access DAS data/event tables in dataset creation step of ML as given in the above guide.